# Navigate from one Stack-Navigator in Drawer-Navigator to another Stack-Navigator in same Drawer-Navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I am trying to navigate from a screen in a stackNavigator (let´s call it stackNavigatorB), which is inside a drawerNavigator, to another screen in another stackNavigator (let´s call it stackNavigatorC), which is inside the same drawerNavigator.

- DrawerNavigator

  - StackNavigatorMain (contains Main Screen)
  - StackNavigatorB
  - - Screen 1 in StackNavigatorB
  - - Screen 2 in StackNavigatorB
  - - Screen 3 in StackNavigatorB
  - StackNavigatorC
  - - Screen 1 in StackNavigatorC
  - - Screen 2 in StackNavigatorC
  - - Screen 3 in StackNavigatorC

Is it possible to navigate from Screen 1,2,3 from StackNavigatorB to Main Screen in StackNavigatorMain or to a Screen in StackNavigatorC? If it is possible, how will it be done? I've been looking for a solution for 3 days already. I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: wich version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @AliSn react-navigation version: 3.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `createSwitchNavigator`

```js
const MyNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Drawer: DrawerNavigator,
  StackB: StackNavigatorB,
  StackC: StackNavigatorC,
});
```

Comment: and how can I navigate from StackNavigatorC from StackC back to DrawerNavigator in Drawer?

Comment: You want me to move to the main screen?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to move from any screen in (for example) StackNavigatorC in StackC to Main-Screen in (for example) StackB.

Comment: If you want to move to the main screen, you can add it to the switch navigator. The screen you add to the switch can be moved anywhere.